# Merge two csv files using PowerShell (header file and data file)

Tags: powershell, csv

**CSV File 1 (Headers File):**

Heading 1, Heading 2, Heading 3 ...

**CSV File 2 (Data File):**

Data Record 1, Data Record 2, Data Record 3 ...

---

File 1 contains the headers only, whereas File 2 contains the data which corresponds to the headers in File 1. 
Is it possible to append the data in File 2, to the Headers in File 1 via a PowerShell script, so File 2 (or a new file) will now look like:

### **Output CSV File**

Heading 1, Heading 2, Heading 3 ...

Data Record 1, Data Record 2, Data Record 3 ...

---

Appologies for the question formatting, first post here. Would you very grateful for any help, thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and we will be happy to help but we won't write you anything from scratch.

Comment: the `Import-CSV` cmdlet has a `-Header` parameter. you could read the 1st file in with `Get-Content` and use that as the value for the header parameter when you use `Import-CSV` on the 2nd file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Headers = (Get-Content csv1.csv).Split(',')
$outputCSV = Import-CSV csv2.csv -Header $Headers
$outputCSV | Export-CSV output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The `$Headers` variable is storing the comma delimited values from the `csv1.csv` file (the file that contains only headers).

The `Split()` method is splitting the contents of `csv1.csv` at each comma, removing the comma, and creating an array of those splits.

`Trim()` can be added after the `Split()` method for removing extra white space around the commas.

`$outputCSV` is importing `csv2.csv` as a csv file and adding the header row from the `$Headers` array.

The final command is exporting the contents of `$outputCSV` into a new csv file called `output.csv`.

In the `Import-CSV` and `Export-CSV` commands, the file names I've provided are assigned to the `-Path` parameter. You can fully qualify those paths if necessary, i.e. they do not have to have just the file names only.

Comment: This worked like a charm!! I just had to remove Trim() as CSV File 2 contains quite a few blanks spaces in the data (unfortunately its produced 3rd party). Once I removed Trim() - it merged the data perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I removed the Trim() method from the answer and just kept it as a note.